# Do we have for $\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{1}{rlog(r)}(\int_0^{2\pi}u(re^{i\theta})d\theta)$ exists for $u$ subharmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $u:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a subharmonic function. Do we have that the limit $\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{1}{rlog(r)}(\int_0^{2\pi}u(re^{i\theta})d\theta)$ converges to a (possibly infinite) value? I have been looking at this for a few hours and I cannot determine the answer. Could anyone show me a solution or give me tips in the right direction?